# sum(list) function Python

Tags: python, function, sum

I have this program which calculates the terms in the Fibonacci sequence; once finished the process i intend to evaluate all even-values and add them to an empty list, then sum all the terms in the list.
But the only line i get for the sum process is ""

NOTE: There are tabulators after the "for" line and the "if" line

```
nt=input("Ingrese el numero de terminos:", )


 w=1                                                                                                
 x=0                      
 y=0            
 z=1          
 print w

for i in xrange(2,nt+1):                                                                              
     y=z+x            
     x=z          
     z=y      
     print z

if z%2==0:             
    list=[]         
    list=list+[input(z)]   
    sum(list)  
print sum
```

Comment: Is your indentation exactly right ? I think your "if" should be indented after the print.

Comment: Fibonacci sequence is `0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...` or `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...`. Your code produces `1, 2, 3, 5, 8, ...` which is not strictly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A somewhat simpler way:

```
nt=input("Ingrese el numero de terminos:", )
fib=[0,1]
for i in range(nt-2):
    fib.append(sum(fib[-2:]))
print sum(i for i in fib if i%2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to acutally assign that to a variable

```
total = sum(list) 
print total
```

Right now, there is no variable for `sum` to return to, so it will calculate the sum, then just move on.

Answer (score 0):

I think your indentation is wrong too, and your code resets your list everytime you find an even number, 2) you should not use "list" as a variable, as it is a special word in python and can cause issues. 3) you don't need to use input when you add something to a list.

Try this version :

```
nt=input("Ingrese el numero de terminos:", )

lst =[]
w=1                                                                                          
x=0     
y=0            
z=1     # could replace 4 lines with w,x,y,z = 1,0,0,1     
print w

for i in xrange(2,nt+1):                                                                              
     y=z+x            
     x=z          
     z=y
     print z

     if z%2==0:                      
         lst=lst+[z]   # Would be better to use append   
 total = sum(list)  
 print total
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Note; both sum and list are built in.  You do not want to have variables
# using these names.
#
# A minimal modification to make it work on both Python2 and Python3.

from __future__ import print_function


nt=int(input("Ingrese el numero de terminos:", ))

w=1
x=0
y=0
z=1
print(w)

lst=[]

for i in range(2,nt+1):
     y=z+x
     x=z
     z=y
     print(z)

     if z%2==0:
        lst.append(z)

print("The sum is", sum(lst))
```